# Enhance performance with for loop and linq query

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate, queryover

i have an object array and i need to get some object Info from database based on certain parameters, i am implementing this:

```
public IList<object[]> GetRelevants(Registro[] records)
    {
        List<object[]> returnList = new List<object[]>();
        using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
        {
            for (int kr = 0; kr < records.Length; kr++)
            {
                Registro record = records[kr];
                var query = session.QueryOver<Registro>()
                                    .Where(sb => sb.Asunto == record.Asunto)
                                    .And(sb => sb.FechaInicial == record.FechaInicial)
                                    .And(sb => sb.FechaFinal == record.FechaFinal)
                                    .And(sb => sb.FoliosDesde == record.FoliosDesde)
                                    .And(sb => sb.FoliosHasta == record.FoliosHasta)
                                    .And(sb => sb.TomoNumero == record.TomoNumero)
                                    .And(sb => sb.TomoTotal == record.TomoTotal)
                                    .And(sb => sb.SerieCodigo == record.SerieCodigo)
                                    .And(sb => sb.Caja == record.Caja)
                                    .And(sb => sb.Carpeta == record.Carpeta).SelectList(list => list
                                      .Select(p => p.Id)
                                      .Select(p => p.NuevaCaja)
                                      .Select(p => p.NuevaCarpeta)
                                      .Select(p => p.Periodo));

                var result = query.SingleOrDefault<object[]>();
                returnList.Add(result);
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

In records however, there are more than 10000 items so NHibernate takes about 10 minutes to do that.

Is there any way to enhance performance in this?

Comment: "Doc it hurts when I do this," ...

Comment: Are you returning the `result` just of the last iteration or are you saving it anywhere? What's the point of the for loop?

Comment: Where did those 10000 Registro records come from? From the same db? In that case the query should run on the DB...

Comment: please show all relevant code when posting questions like this ..it makes it very difficult for others to see what you have done up to this `for loop for example` for example how is records defined and or populated..2nd what does the method signature look like that you are using.. what's the return type if any.. also what are you doing with `result` once you have assigned it..???

Comment: Sorry, i just ask an incomplete question, in this moment i am only testing performance then Yes, i must return a IList<object[]> result is added to this IList in each iteration to make a semicolon separated file, the 10000 or more Registro objects are read from a third party csv generated file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution would probably be to ditch NHibernate for this task and insert your data into a temporary table, then join on that temporary table.

However, if you want to use NHibernate, you could speed this up by not issuing 10,000 separate queries (which is what's happening now). You could try to break your query into reasonably sized chunks instead:

```
List<object[]> ProcessChunk(
    IStatelessSession session,
    int start,
    IEnumerable<Registro> currentChunk)
{
    var disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();

    foreach (var item in currentChunk)
    {
        var restriction = Restrictions.Conjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.Where<Registro>(t => t.Asunto == item.Asunto))
            /* etc, calling .Add(..) for every field you want to include */

        disjunction.Add(restriction);
    }

    return session.QueryOver<Registro>()
        .Where(disjunction)
        .SelectList(list => list
            .Select(t => t.Id)
            /* etc, the rest of the select list */
        .List<object[]>()
        .ToList();
}
```

Then call that method from your main loop:

```
const int chunkSize = 500;   

for (int kr = 0; kr < records.Length; kr += chunkSize)
{
    var currentChunk = records.Skip(i).Take(chunkSize);

    resultList.AddRange(ProcessChunk(session, i, currentChunk));
}
```

What you're doing here is issuing 20 (instead of 10,000) queries that look like:

```sql
select
    /* select list */
from
    [Registro]
where
    ([Registro].[Asunto] = 'somevalue' and ... and ... and .. ) or
    ([Registro].[Asunto] = 'someothervalue' and ... and ... and ... )
    /* x500, one for each item in the chunk */
```

and so on. Each query will return up to 500 records if 500 is the size of each chunk.

This is still not going to be blazing fast. My local test about halved the running time.

Depending on your database engine, you might quickly run up against a maximum number of parameters that you can pass. You'll probably have to play with the `chunkSize` to get it to work.

You could probably get this down to a few seconds if you used a temporary table and ditched NHibernate though.

Comment: Thanks in advance, i am going to implement that, i will stay in contact to tell you the art status... jeje

Comment: I just watched an excellent blog of you @Andrew Whitaker, there is something i call a "good explained job" with very clearly examples and the most important topic: the translation from NHibernate to SQL native sentences, i like that blog a lot! thanks to Andrew Whitaker for creating http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/

Comment: Finally i found @Andrew Whitaker answer very useful, Thanks a lot, it works fine for me, processing 1.000.072 records in 7 minutes!.